# Need help hooking up XML file to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, mvvm

**Here's what I've done so far:**

1. In my `App` class, I declare a new `XmlDataProvider` and set the source to a valid XML file (whose Build Action is set to Content/Copy Always).

   ```
   public partial class App : Application
   {
       public App()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           var services = new XmlDataProvider();
           services.Source = new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Data/Services.xml"); // also tried an absolute path, but that made no difference
           var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
           mainWindow.DataContext = new MainViewModel(services);
           mainWindow.Show();
       }
   }
   ```
2. The `XmlDataProvider` gets passed into the ViewModel and gets assigned to the `Services` property.
3. I bind to the data like this:

   ```
   <mwc:DataGrid
       ItemsSource="{Binding Services, XPath=//Services/*}">
       <mwc:DataGrid.Columns>
           <mwc:DataGridTextColumn
               Binding="{Binding XPath=@name}"
               Header="Name" />
           <mwc:DataGridTextColumn ... />
           ...
       </mwc:DataGrid.Columns>
   </mwc:DataGrid>
   ```

**The result:**

The column headings of my `DataGrid` show up, but there are no rows of data. It compiles and runs without any errors, but if I check my Output window, I see this:

```
BindingExpression with XPath cannot bind to non-XML object.;
XPath='//Services/*'
BindingExpression:Path=Services;
```

**Can the XmlDataProvider only be used declaratively?**

If I attempt to create the `XmlDataProvider` declaratively in a `ResourceDictionary` like this...

```
<XmlDataProvider
    x:Key="Main_Services">
    <x:XData>
        <Services
            xmlns="">
            <Service
                name="Test"
                ... />
            <Service ... />
            ...
        </Services>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

...everything works fine (I get the expected rows in my `DataGrid`). (Note that I just pasted the contents of the XML file between the `<x:XData>` tags.)

If I try to set the `Source` via C#, however, there doesn't seem to be any data in the `XmlDataProvider` (literally, the `Data` property is null).

It doesn't seem to make any difference whether I use a "pack URI" or an absolute path when I assign the `Source`. I get no rows either way. I also tried calling the `InitialLoad()` method after setting the source, but that made no difference either.

**Questions:**

- Is XmlDataProvider just the wrong tool for the job or am I doing something wrong?
- Can XmlDataProvider only be used declaratively?
- I know there is `XDocument` and `XmlDocument`...should I be using one of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarative seems to be the way to go. This code works:

```
<XmlDataProvider
    x:Key="Main_Services"
    Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Data/Services.xml">
</XmlDataProvider>
```

I have no idea why doing the same exact thing in C# fails, but I can live with this solution.